# iPhone take photo on phone unlock

Tags: iphone, ios, camera

I doubt this is possible, but here's what I want to do. If my app is running in the background, I want the phone to automatically take a photo whenever the phone is unlocked. It would all happen automatically, without any of the UIImagePickerController stuff or anything. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's possible, and quite easy, but you need to get down and dirty with MobileSubstrate, Springboard Class dumps and stuff like that. Like they already said, there's no way you could distribute this via the AppStore, and you'd need a jailbroken iPhone. It's not novice stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  There is no way to accomplish this unless the phone is unlocked.  No app in the App Store would be able to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Not with public APIs, at least. There is no way to take a photo without going through the camera interface.